# Separate numbers from string in DataFrame

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['rob12','mark kevin34','john'], 'B' : ['aa','bb','dd'], 'C':[10,34,98]})

and I want to delete the numbers from the first column to get a column like A ['rob', 'mark kevin', 'john']. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want apply this approach to all columns or just to column A?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()` and `apply()` to apply this to column `A`.

Input:

```
df
              A   B   C
0         rob12  aa  10
1  mark kevin34  bb  34
2          john  dd  98
```

Code:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[\d-]", "", x))
```

On larger data frames you should use `map()` instead of `apply()`;

```
df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: re.sub("[\d-]", "", x))
```

Output:

```
df
            A   B   C
0         rob  aa  10
1  mark kevin  bb  34
2        john  dd  98
```